# Preventing users from creating multiple accounts on my server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a game I originally wrote for PC that I'm now porting to ios.

It is an online multiplayer game that requires the user to have an account with us. To do this they sign up and register right in the game.

We want to try to prevent the same user creating lots of accounts. If it happens it's not critical, but we want to diminish it.

On PC we store a file in app data saying an account has been created with this computer. so it is hard for the average user to circumvent that.

Unfortunately on ios, there does not seem to be a way to permanently store something to prevent the user from creating multiple accounts. They can uninstall and reinstall the app, clear keychain data, etc.

What is / are some ways that can be used  help prevent multiple account creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually keychain items are not cleared on app uninstall. You can store their playerId there. And you can fetch that the next time user installs the app.

There is no sure shot way using which you can prevent users from creating multiple accounts. At most you can make it difficult for an average user to do so.