# What's the best way to identify an iPhone UID in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to know the unique ID of that iPhone. How can I get that in Swift? 
Is it allowed by Apple to store it? We use it to ensure that people don't create multiple accounts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing users from creating multiple accounts on my server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790206/preventing-users-from-creating-multiple-accounts-on-my-server)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get an unique string identifier in Swift:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
```

This code returns a identifier that is unique for the device. Please note it does not return Apple's Unique Device Identifier (UDID), which is a sequence of 40 letters and numbers as Apple has hidden the UDID from all public APIs, starting with iOS 7.

Comment: Is that allowed from Apple's policies?

Comment: Yes, as the code does not return the Apple UDID, it  just returns an identifier that is unique for your device. You can't get Apple's  UDID through any API calls since IOS7.